# How to dynamically create, set, and use conditional?

Tags: programming

It is better if I give an illustration as follows.

### A statically created and invoked macro

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}{test}
\mymacro
```

### A dynamically created and invoked macro

```
\expandafter\csname mymacro\endcsname{test}
\csname mymacro\endcsname
```

### A statically created, set and used conditional

```
\newif\ifIsInserted
\IsInsertedtrue

\ifIsInserted
    It has been inserted.
\else
    It has not been inserted yet.
\fi
```

## Question

How to dynamically create, set and invoke conditional?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% statically created macro
% \newcommand{\mymacro}{test}
% \mymacro

% dynamically created macro
\expandafter\csname mymacro\endcsname{test}
\csname mymacro\endcsname


% statically created conditional
\newif\ifIsInserted
\IsInsertedtrue

\ifIsInserted
    It has been inserted.
\else
    It has not been inserted yet.
\fi


% dynamically created conditional
% ?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\expandafter\newif\csname ifIsInserted\endcsname
\csname IsInsertedtrue\endcsname
```

defines `\IsInsertedtrue` but if you have that as part of another macro you can replace `IsInsertedtrue` by `#1` or any other constructs that you need.

Note

```
% dynamically created macro
\expandafter\csname mymacro\endcsname{test}
```

does not create a macro, I assume you meant

```
% dynamically created macro
\expandafter\def\csname mymacro\endcsname{test}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `\expandafter\csname mymacro\endcsname{test}` and `\expandafter\def\csname mymacro\endcsname{test}`?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian The first one does nothing useful `\expandafter` applies to `m` which isn't expandable so it is equivalent to `\relax{test}` so will typeset `test` at that point. The second one defines `\mymacro` to be `test`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\Create[2][false]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname#2\endcsname{#2}%
    \expandafter\newif\csname if#2\endcsname \csname#2#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\Create{test} \iftest \test \fi % prints nothing

\Create[true]{Test} \ifTest \Test \fi % prints Test
\end{document}
```